# How to display data from two separate tables in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So, i am new to programming and i am trying to make my  first .net project, and i'm stuck.

I have a database that contains table Product, it looks like this:

```
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public double ProductPrice { get; set; }

    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }

    public string ProductImagePath { get; set; }
   
    public int ProductColorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductColorId")]
    public virtual ProductColor ProductColor { get; set; }

   
    public int ProductShippingOptionId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductShippingOptionId")]
    public virtual ProductShippingOption ProductShippingOption { get; set; }

    
    
    public int ProductConditionId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductConditionId")]
    public virtual ProductCondition ProductCondition { get; set; }
```

Columns ProductShippingOption, ProductColor and ProductCondition are a separate tables that each contain columns for Id and Name.

When i add a product to database, i want to show details of just one product in a view, but i need to display ProductConditionName instead of ProductConditionId (for example).

What  should i include in my ViewModel and my Controller so i can use it in my View?

My action in a ProductController looks like this

```
public IActionResult ProductTemplate(int? id)
    {
        ProductVM productVM = new ProductVM()
        {
            Product = _db.Product.Find(id),
            
        };

        if (id == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (id == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

       

        if(productVM==null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(productVM);

    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best and easiest way to do it is including the classes in Product:

For your ProductTemplate action :

```
ProductVM productVM = new ProductVM()
{


    Product = _db.Product.Where(s=>s.Id == id)
                         .Include(s=>s.ProductColor)
                         .Include(s=>s.ProductShippingOption)
                         .Include(s=>s.ProductCondition)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
};
```

And you can call them in your .cshtml with (Let say you want ProductColor name) :

```
@Model.Product.ProductColor.Name
```

Alternatively you can add `Include()` to your context to take all includes defaultly.

Comment: Pretty sure the `Include` has to go before the `Find`, since `Find` triggers enumeration on your queryable. You can get away with adding the includes later in cases where there is no enumeration being triggered yet (e.g. after a `Where`), but not after the enumeration has already happened (`Find`, `Single`, `First`, ...)

Comment: Thanks, I usually use "Where" so didn't know that we can't include after find. Edited accordingly

Comment: No problem, it's a simple thing to gloss over. This does somewhat invalidate the advice in your last paragraph. Regardless of where you put the `Include` (so long as it's before enumeration), it works exactly the same way. There's not really a way to "add it to your context" by changing the order of the chained method (again, I'm ignoring post-enumeration as that simply doesn't work).